# I can't paint the rows of another page in the gridview, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I can't solve one thing, I want to paint some rows of the GridView depending on a column. I have no problems with this, but when I change the page, I can't get it to paint.

This is how I do the pagination

```
    GridView2.PageIndex =  e.NewPageIndex;
        loadgrid();
        paintpagin(e.NewPageIndex);
```

So I try to paint it

GridView2.PageIndex = newPageIndex;

```
        foreach (GridViewRow Rowe in GridView2.Rows)
        {
                CheckBox Rc = (CheckBox)Rowe.FindControl("rdaprobar");
                RadioButton Ri = (RadioButton)Rowe.FindControl("rdpendiente");
                RadioButton Rd = (RadioButton)Rowe.FindControl("rdCandelar");

                if (Rc.Checked == true)
                {
                    GridView2.Rows[Rowe.DataItemIndex].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#bcf5be");
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The even to use for highlights, formatting, etc.?

use the Grid row data bound event.

So, first up, our markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            width="45%" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="GHotels_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GHotels_PageIndexChanging"   >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HotelName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="270" />
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code to load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = 
                "SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE Description is not null ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GHotels.DataSource = rstData;
                GHotels.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Our pager code (and NOTE YOU HAVE the load of the grid before the pager - chec your code!!!).

```
    protected void GHotels_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GHotels.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        LoadData();

    }
```

Ok, we now have this:

Now, I highlight each hotel if it is active. NOTE very careful, I don't have that column "active" in the GV, but it was/is part of the data source. So, for bonus points, I demonstrate how to get/grab/use columns that you don't render or have in the GV, but in fact is part of the data source.

So, our code to highlight, we have this:

```
    protected void GHotels_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // get binding data source                
            DataRowView gData = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            if ((bool)gData["Active"]) {
                // Label tHotel = e.Row.FindControl("txtHotel") as Label;
                // tHotel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
                e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, we now have this:

[image]

So do NOT try and loop each row of the GV - use the row data bound to highlight and format as per above.